# Pass multiple commands to flock

Tags: shell, command-line, lock, flock

```
flock -x -w 5 ~/counter.txt 'COUNTER=$(cat ~/counter.txt); echo $((COUNTER + 1)) > ~/counter.txt'
```

How would I pass multiple commands to `flock` as in the example above?

As far as I understand, `flock` takes different flags (-x for exclusive, -w for timeout), then the file to lock, and then the command to run. I'm not sure how I would pass two commands into this function (set variable with locked file's contents, and then increment this file).

My goal here is to create a somewhat atomic increment for a file by locking it each time a script tries to access the `counter.txt` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoke a shell explicitly.

```
flock -x -w 5 ~/counter.txt sh -c 'COUNTER=$(cat counter.txt); echo $((COUNTER + 1)) > ~/counter.txt'
```

Note that any variable that you change is local to that shell instance. For example, the `COUNTER` variable will not be updated in the calling script: you'll have to read it back from the file (but it may have changed in the meantime), or as the output of the command:

```
new_counter=$(flock -x -w 5 ~/counter.txt sh -c 'COUNTER=$(cat counter.txt); echo $((COUNTER + 1)) | tee ~/counter.txt')
```

Comment: awesome, thanks so much! The explanation you provided definitely saved me from another hour of headaches

Answer (score 4):

Or you can flock a file descriptor

```
exec {counterfd}<~/counter.txt
flock -x -w 5 "$counterfd"
COUNTER=$(cat ~/counter.txt)
COUNTER=$(( COUNTER +1 ))
echo "$COUNTER" >~/counter.txt
exec {counterfd}<&-
```

This also has the benefit of allowing you to use the counter variable directly, unlike subshell based approaches.

Comment: Please would you explain the `exec {counterfd}`? On its own, Debian errors `not found`, but it returns 0 with the redirection. Very odd.

Answer (score 3):

The `flock` tool is a little tricky to use and the man page is pretty short. The man page provides three ways to use the tool:

- `flock [options] <file|directory> <command> [command args]`
- `flock [options] <file|directory> -c <command>`
- `flock [options] <file descriptor number>`

The way this question is worded I would definitely use the third form of `flock`. If you go further down in the man page for `flock` there are some examples which show the exact syntax for using the third form:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
 flock -n 9 || exit 1
 echo "commands executed under lock..."
 echo "go here..."
) 9>/tmp/mylockfile
```

I added the `#!/bin/bash`.

I have successfully used this form of `flock`.

Answer (score -1):

I had an interesting use case. I had to run my python script as cronjob using flock, every 30 minute. And due to some root path related stuff inside my python script instead of

```
python /home/myfolder/script.py
```

I needed to do

```
cd /home/myfolder/ && python script.py
```

To pass both commands in crontab -

```
*/30 * * * * cd /home/myfolder/ /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /home/myfolder/my-file.lock && python my_script.py > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Ok, but this technically solves the issue of running multiple commands while locking though _not running multiple commands while locking_.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about your comment? I might have understood it wrongly.  It would help me improve my approach.

Comment: Sorry. It seems that you solved the issue of running two separate commands while using `flock` by rearranging the command in such a way that you run the first command (`cd`) before invoking `flock`.  This results in locking only while executing the _single_ command `python`. Hence my comment above. You also have a syntax error in your second crontab schedule (after the argument to `cd` there should be a `&&` or `;`).